# about the route to connect a SQLite databases in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is the code to connect the database named "library.db" in the assets file.

```
public abstract class DBConstant {
    //database file directory
    public static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/(pack_name)/databases";
    //database file name
    public static String DATABASE_FILE = "library.db";
    //database version
    public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
}
```

However, in my laptop, the laptop with windows or the laptop with mac os, the app cannot find the .db file. After edit the `/databases` to `/assets`, all goes well. Another weird is that when I edit it back to `/databases`, it goes well on my laptop with windows, but become failed on other laptops.

What can that happen? There seems no difference in other codes.

Comment: do you `clean` and `compile` properly ?

Comment: ok, may that work. I found clean project, run on the emulator is compile, right? I am new in the android, sorry.

Comment: Why are you using an explicit path? You should use [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), or [getDatabasePath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

On compile it *suppose* to convert to the right separator I believe, but platform independent would look something like this:

```
String path = File.separator + "data"+ File.separator + "data" + File.separator + "pack_name" + File.separator + "databases";
```

see Questions: [File.separator or File.pathSeparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971964/file-separator-or-file-pathseparator) and [Why is File.separator in Android using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558780/why-is-file-separator-in-android-using) and [Difference between File.separator and slash in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths)

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is the reason, but the knowledge is useful in the future programming. Thx anyway.